# How to show the PHP Laravel applications logs in docker logs?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

How to show the PHP Laravel applications logs in docker logs?

Logs are coming fine in php8.0-fpm.log file but not in docker console.

Tried the following

- Added the sym links
  ln -s /dev/stderr /var/log/php8.0-fpm.log
- Changed the error_log=/var/log/php8.0-fpm.log to error_log=/proc/self/fd/2
  in php-fpm.conf
- Added catch_workers_output=yes in /etc/php/8.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

Answer (score 2):

You can change the log channel for Laravel to `stderr`.

Either by using the LOG_CHANNEL environment variable or by changing the default logging configuration to `stderror` in `config/logging.php`:

```php
'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stderr'),
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Sorry, I forgot to mention that. I already did that

Comment: No luck with that